# Spring-Hibernate:: How to Ensure data is transmitted correctly from the DB to the Web Server / end user browser and back

Tags: hibernate, spring, locking

I am using a spring hibernate combination for my web application, but I wanted to ensure that when I read particular data from the db it does not change before I update or save the record.
Can this be applied through pessimistic locking?

Thanks in advance..Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports both optimistic and pessimistic locking. See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking).

When using optimistic locking, if you update the record after somebody already changed it, you'll get an error, so you won't overwrite those changes.

With pessimistic locking, you can ask for a write lock before allowing user to modify data, and if such a lock can't be obtained, you can display some kind of message to user asking him to try again later.

Bear in mind that optimistic locking is way more scalable.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I have seen the documentation for pessimistic locking. But it is only advisable to use session.lock() only if you are absolutely sure that the detached object is in sync with your detached object or if it does not matter because you will be overwriting all the columns that would have changed later on within the same transaction.In my case I am using getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(tempEmp), which automatically acquires lock for such transactions as per my knowledge. Please explain how may I apply and benefit through Pessimistic locking.